# FLEX C++ yytext function

Tags: c++, lex

The code isn't wrote in English(variable names, but that shouldn't be a problem).
The yytext function doesn't copy what I want to copy. Here is the relevant code from .l file:

```
`progr: declaratii bloc {printf("program corect sintactic\n");}
     ;

declaratii :  declaratie ';'
       | declaratii declaratie ';'
       | declaratii structura 
       | declaratii clasa ';'
       | declaratii function 
       | function
       | clasa ';'
       | structura 
       ;

declaratie : INT var_int 
           | INT lista_int
           | CHAR var_char
           | CHAR lista_char
           | FLOAT var_float
           | FLOAT lista_float
           | STRING var_string
           | STRING lista_string
           | BOOL var_bool
           | BOOL lista_bool
           ;

lista_int : ID '(' lista_param_int ')' {add("lista", "int");}
     | ID '(' ')' {add("lista", "int");}
     | lista_int ',' ID '(' lista_param_int ')' {add("lista", "int");}
     | lista_int ',' ID '(' ')' {add("lista", "int");}
     ;
var_int : ID {add("var", "int");}
     | var_int ','  ID {add("var", "int");}
     ;
lista_param_int : INT ID 
            | lista_param_int ',' INT ID 
            ;

lista_char : ID '(' lista_param_char ')' {add("lista", "char");}
     | ID '(' ')' {add("lista", "char");}
     | lista_char ',' ID '(' lista_param_char ')' {add("lista", "char");}
     | lista_char ',' ID '(' ')' {add("lista", "char");}
     ;


void add(char * tip, char * tipDate){
     symbol_table[contor].nume = strdup(yytext) ;
     symbol_table[contor].tip = tip;
     symbol_table[contor].tipDate = tipDate;
     contor++;
}
```

Here is the text file (input):

```
class Test{
    private:
        int @x;
    public:
        int @z;
    protected:
        char @o;
        int @tr2;
    protected:
        float @k;
        int @dasdas(int @var23);
};
struct structura{
    char @nume;
    char @tip;
};

float functie($int @var0 : char @sir : bool @binar){
    $int @var1;
    $@var1 := 1;
    $if'(@var1 :== 1){
        @var1 := 2;
        if'(@var1 :== 2){
            @var1 := 3;
        }
    }
    $@var1 := 8;
    $int @var2;
    $int @var3, @var4;
    $@var2 := 6;
}

int @a, @b, @c;
int @xz, @dsada;
int @d(), @xsadas(int @arata);
char @c;
begin_progr
@a := 3;
if'(@a :== 3){
    @a := 2;
}
end_progr
```

And there is the output (It copys corectly only the variables which are after the ',' as you see):

```
nume      tip      tipDate
;          var      int      
;          var      int      
;          var      char      
;          var      int      
;          var      float      
)          lista      int      
;          var      char      
;          var      char      
:          var      int      
:          var      char      
)          var      bool      
;          var      int      
;          var      int      
,          var      int      
@var4          var      int      
,          var      int      
@b          var      int      
@c          var      int      
,          var      int      
@dsada          var      int      
)          lista      int      
)          lista      int      
;          var      char
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`yytext` is a variable, not a function. Moreover, it's a variable whose value is only available inside a (f)lex action.

Making a copy of `yytext` inside a parser action is way too late. You have to do it in the lexer action.

Every time the lexer is asked for a new token, it overwrites `yytext`, so at best `yytext` is the last token  in the production. But it might be the next token, because sometimes the parser needs to look at the next token before it knows it can reduce a production.

Comment: Ok, so I have to move the function from the parser into .l file? How do I do that?

Comment: @fabi: That's not what I'm saying. You have to do the `strdup` in the lexer, but you can't call `add` from the lexer because at that point, it's not known what the role of the variable name is. You should start by reading the section in the Bison manual about [semantic values](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics), where it shows you how to attach a value to each grammar symbol (both tokens and non-terminals). Then you have to figure out what would be a good semantic type for an identifier. An obvious choice is to just use the copy of the identifier string...

Comment: @fabi: ... which might be a good place to start, since you still need to do a lot of work on your symbol table implementation. You should also think about how to represent data types (`int`, `char`, etc.): using a literal character string is far from optimal, and the code duplication in your grammar which comes from making each data type a separate production will prove to be unsustainable. Furthermore, you seem to allow the definition of structure and class types, which means that the set of possible types in a program cannot be expressed as a predefined list of legal alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it, but I really a really fast solution for that, I need to solve the yytext problem with the code I already have, do you have a simple and practical solution?

Comment: @fabi: No, I don't, because the code you have is unworkable. If by "a fast solution" you mean, "please do my assignment for me", I'm sorry, but I'll have to turn down that offer. Even if I wanted to spend the next couple of hours doing that --which I don't--, I can't because I don't have a clue what your requirements are (and I'm not sure that you do, either).

Comment: The best "simple" example of using a symbol table with Bison is the extended example in Chapter 3 of John Levine's book *Flex and Bison*, published by O'Reilly. But I fear that it is not as simple as you would like.